# How to use the COPY command to insert the bulk json documents in the postgreSQL table

Tags: json, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2, bulkinsert

I am trying to insert (bulk insert) the list of documents using COPY like below using python 3.5, but its not working as expected or do we need to use `executemany` or other.

The Postgres table look like this.

```
create table payments(id serial primary key, info jsonb)
```

query like this below:

```
cur = self.configDBclient.cursor()
sql = "COPY %s(info) FROM %s;"
cur.execute(sql, (AsIs('payments'), Json(pDocList),))
self.configDBclient.commit()
cur.close()
```

UPDATED:
 not only copy or else, at least how to bulk insert in PostgreSQL

Comment: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from

Comment: can you please give an example for inserting bulk insert json documents

Comment: Sorry, never used it myself. There are examples in the [docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from).

Comment: "bulk insert" can be done using `insert into payments (info) values ('{...}'), ('{...}'), ('{...}'), ('{...}'), ('{...}');`

Comment: What is data format in the file? Show a single line as an example.

Comment: its not a file, its just a JsonArray like pDoc = [{
    "CoverageEndDt": "20180228",
    "RecordType": "E"
},{
    "CoverageEndDt": "20180228",
    "RecordType": "E"
}]